# Why is smoothness required to define a vector space and the tangent space?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

Suppose $M$ is a manifold. The tangent space at a point $p$, $T_pM$, is defined to be the set of all derivations:
$$T_pM = \{D: C^\infty(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ~|~ D(fg)(x) = f(x)D(g)(x) + g(x)D(f)(x)\}.$$
A vector field $X$ is then defined as assigning $d \in T_pM$ to each $p \in M$.

When defining vector fields and tangent spaces, I am not surprised that we impose some degree of smoothness due to how tangent spaces are defined using derivatives in basic calculus.  But I have been wondering what would happen if we were to relax the domain of $T_pM$ and hence of $X$ in the more abstract definition above. For example, instead of defining the derivations to be over $C^\infty$, what if we were to define it to be over $C^0$? This would allow us to define vector fields and tangent spaces on any topological manifold, but I read a comment that this is impossible and they can only be defined on smooth manifolds. Is there any particular reason for this and we define the derivations to be over $C^\infty$?

Comment: In short, the reason is that the set of derivations of the algebra of continuous functions is reduced to $\{0\}$. The explanation can be found [somewhere on this website for sure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014634/do-exotic-vectorfields-exist).  You can show it on $\Bbb R$ by looking at the continuous function $x\mapsto |x|$

Comment: @Didier Thank you, this is quite interesting.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Jet Nestruev's *Smooth Manifolds and Observables.* You're absolutely right, quite a few differential-geometric constructions can be made sense of in terms of commutative algebra over the ring $C^\infty(X)$, but as Didier's comment indicates, strange things can happen if you try to play the same games over $C(X)$, for instance.